# SunOS Sorting By Date

Tags: sorting, unix, find, exec, solaris

I'm currently running the following on a directory:

```
find `pwd` -type f -exec grep -s -i -l '$string' {} + | xargs -L 1 ls -lrthg | sort -k7 -k6
```

It arranges all returned files by date (Year). I'm close to what I want but I can't get it to sort all the months together in sequential day order.

I'm Running on an old version of SunOS (5.10).

I can't upgrade or install anything so this has been a challenge.  I also can't use perl.  Help would be greatly appreciated.

[From bottom up (1)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oMLwl.png)
[From bottom up (2)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hPWqi.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what you might do to achieve that with the standard Solaris commands :

```
find . -type f -exec grep -sil "$string" {} + | xargs -L 1 ls -Erth | sort -k 6,7
```

Comment: You sir/madam are amazing.  That got me exactly what I needed.  Thank you very much.